# Getting cases percentage as null when running the following code

Tags: mysql

Getting cases percentage as null when running the following code

```
 SELECT   location,
         date,
         population,
         total_cases,
         (try_cast(total_cases as DECIMAL(10,2))/nullif(try_cast(population AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0))*100.0 AS cases_percentage
FROM     portfolioproject..coviddeaths
WHERE    location ='India'
ORDER BY 1,
         2
```

Tried this code-

```
 SELECT   location,
         date,
         population,
         total_cases,
         (try_cast(total_cases as DECIMAL(10,2))/nullif(try_cast(population AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0))*100.0 AS cases_percentage
FROM     portfolioproject..coviddeaths
WHERE    location ='India'
ORDER BY 1,
         2
```

Comment: If you change your where clause from `where location ='India' and total_case is not null and population is not null`, do you get reasonable results? If you do get reasonable results, you could change your `(try_cast(total_cases....` line with: `case when total_cases is null then 0 when population is null then 0 else cast(total_cases as decimal(10,2)) * 100 / cast(population as decimal(10,2)) end as cases_percent` and see if you get the expected results. If you do, you can change your where clause to `where location='India'` and see if you get all your results as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided tries to calculate the percentage of total cases in the population by dividing `total_cases` by `population` and then multiplying by `100`. However, there are a couple of reasons why the result might be showing as `NULL`.

**Data Issues**: There might be `NULL` or incorrect values in the `total_cases` or `population` columns for India in the table. Check the data to ensure it is clean and accurate.

**Data Types and Casting**: The casting of `total_cases` and `population` to `DECIMAL(10,2)` might be causing issues. It's a good practice to use explicit casting, but make sure that the data types you're casting to are appropriate for the data. For example, if the `total_cases` or `population` are large numbers, `DECIMAL(10,2)` might not be sufficient. Try increasing the precision.

**Division by Zero**: You are correctly handling division by zero by using `NULLIF`, which will return `NULL` if the population is `0`. However, if you have `NULL` values in the data, it would also return `NULL` as the result.

Here is a modified version of your code which should work better by using a higher precision and also handling `NULL` values:

```
SELECT   location,
         date,
         population,
         total_cases,
         COALESCE((try_cast(total_cases as DECIMAL(18,6)) / NULLIF(try_cast(population AS DECIMAL(18,6)), 0)) * 100.0, 0) AS cases_percentage
FROM     portfolioproject..coviddeaths
WHERE    location ='India'
ORDER BY 1,
         2;
```

This code uses `COALESCE` to handle `NULL` values. If the division result is `NULL` (either due to division by zero or `NULL` values in the data), it will return `0`.